# Topological invariant in 1D

Tags: topological-insulators, graphene, berry-pancharatnam-phase

In 2D, with state $\psi(k_x, k_y)$, it is common to calculate measure of topology of material:

1 - Calculate Berry connection $a = -i <\psi | \partial_{\boldsymbol{k}} | \psi>$.

2 - Calculate Berry curvature $F = \partial_{k_x} a_y -\partial_{k_y} a_x $.

3 -  Define topological invariant (Chern number) $C = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int F(k_x, k_y) \mathrm{d}k_x \mathrm{d}k_y$.

How to calculate an analogous topological invariant for a 1D state $\psi(k_x)$?

Naively, the above recipe can never give a non-zero topological invariant since the Berry curvature vansihes. However, 1D topological insulators are well known to exist.

Comment: Be precise! *What* problem with Berry curvature is there? (I think you mean that it vanishes, and that's correct. Curvature is a 2-form - one-dimensional objects don't *have* curvature unless they're embedded into a higher space) Do you have reason to believe there *should* be a similar invariant in 1D?

Comment: @ACuriousMind I tried to clarify my question. My misunderstanding is how to build a similar recipe for a topological invariant in 1D. I believe there should be one since there are 1D topological insulators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are similar topological invariants for band structures in one dimension, but an important difference is that these invariants always require some symmetry in the band Hamiltonians, for example particle-hole symmetry. In such cases, typically the invariant is given by

$$
C=\int\frac{dk}{2\pi} a_k \text{ mod }1
$$

Comment: I suppose you meant to have $\mathrm{mod}\,1$ on RHS?

Comment: @Meng Cheng Thank you for answer. The $C$ you define looks similar to the Berry phase but divided by $2 \pi$. Therefore, a band with nontrivial Berry phase of $\pi$ has non-integer $C = 1/2$. Is this why you say there is needed another symmetry? For example a 2 band problem, both with Berry phase of $\pi$ would suggest $C = 1/2 + 1/2 = 1$?

Comment: The $1/2\pi$ is a normalization factor. In the particle-symmetric insulator case, the physical meaning of $C$ is the polarization charge on the edge of the system, which is NOT quantized in the absence of symmetry. With particle-hole symmetry, it can only takes 0 or $e/2$. This is because the polarization $P$ has to be equal to $-P$, but $P$ is only defined up to $e$. Therefore the classification is $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: @higgsss You are right, it should be defined mod $1$.