# Chern number in one-dimensional system

Tags: condensed-matter, topological-insulators, topological-phase

As the title, could we define Chern number for condensed matter systems with one spatial dimension? E.g. the 1D Su-Schrieffer–Heeger (SSH) model.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/241006/50583

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not define Chern number for 1D system, but you can define the **winding number** (another topological index) for 1D system, which can be used to characterize the topological phases in the SSH model. One still start with the Berry connection $A=\langle u_k|\mathrm{i}\partial_k|u_k\rangle\mathrm{d}k$ (in terms of the differential 1-form). In 1D, the Berry connection has only one component. Then define winding number
$$P_1=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_\text{BZ}A.$$
Unlike the Chern number which is quantized, and any different integer value of the Chern number labels a different topological phase. The winding number is not quantized in general, and two winding numbers differed by $1$ are equivalent (i.e. $P_1\sim P_1+1$). This is where symmetry becomes important. Under time-reversal symmetry (of the symmetry class DIII), the winding number is reversed $P_1\to-P_1$. So if the symmetry is preserved, the winding number can only take two values $P_1=0,1/2$ (note that $1/2=-1/2$ because of the mod $1$ periodicity). In this case, the winding number labels different phases in the SSH model. $P_1=0$ corresponds to the trivial phase and $P_1=1/2$ corresponds to the topological phase.